# Why does a view returns different results from its SELECT

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm going mad trying to understand what's going on.

I have created a simple view checking if there are records in the Financial table which don't have a counterpart in the Plans table (column group is not null):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create view vFinCheck as 

select f.Group, f.Country, f.Revenue
from  Finances f
left join Plans p
on f.Group = p.Group and f.Country = p.Country
where p.Group is null

GO
```

When I run the select inside the view definition I get 6 rows - correctly identifying records missing in the Plans table.
But when I run `select * from vFinCheck` I will get 17 rows - those 6 as from the previous select and 11 more (incorrectly).

Both are run against the same data source (it did not change for days), and the same database.

It seemed as if the issue is the join statement but I dont know why.
Another weird thing is that when I query the results of the view (identifying rows that cannot be joined to the Plans table) and join them with the Plans table it works correctly.

```
select *
from vFinCheck c
join Plans p
on c.Group = p.Group and c.Country = p.Country
```

This query returns those 11 records which should not be returned by the view in the first place, proving that those records can be joined with the Plans table.

I tried dropping and recreating the view multiple times - did not help.
Is there any reason why should a view return something different than its select?

Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Comment: Sounds like there's something *else* going on here, if I am honest. What happens if you properly schema qualify your objects? (You should be doing that anyway.) Do you get the same behaviour if you also use a `NOT EXISTS` rather than a `LEFT JOIN` too?

Comment: My first thought was the same. Are you looking at the same tables with the view as you are with the select?

Comment: could you please provide sample data?

Comment: @Larnu NOT EXIST made no difference. But adding [dbo] did solve the issue - thank you!! Can you explain to me why?  I know it is good practice and it impacts performance but how can it return different data than the same select?! Why is not the behavior of the view and its select the same in this regard?

Comment: *"I know it is good practice and it impacts performance but how can it return different data than the same select?!"* Because if the `USER` you are connected to have different default schemas, you aren't querying the same object(s).

Comment: @Larnu but when I check sys.dm_exec_requests when running the simple select, or querying the view the user_id is the same (nothing is run automatically it is just me with the same query windows querying one or the other). Also in sys.database_principals all users have the same default schema (except for guest).

Comment: With a [mre] there's little more I can do but guess, @ddeiml . I don't have access to your instance.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your scenario in my system, and I am getting expected output for both Queries output as records missing in the Plans table. [See Here](https://i.imgur.com/DMri04i.png)

Comment: My suspicion is that the query you are referencing in your select is not the same as is being created. I suggest you check to make sure that you haven't accidentally created the same view under more than one database or under two schemas in the same database.  In particular, check the master database to make sure you haven't accidentally created a view there. Another suggestion is to add something unique to the view definition (`SELECT 'here', ...`) and see if that shows up in your select from view results.